# Showing one record from DB on the left side, and the next one on right

Tags: html

I splitted my page into two parts and I would like to have the results from the database display from left to right. For now, the left side and the right side displays the same record. How to do, that the left side will display first record, and the right side the next one and so on?

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT company_province, company_district, company_city, company_name, tel, company_nip, company_desc FROM test WHERE company_province = '$woj' AND company_district = '$pow' AND company_city = '$nazwa' ORDER BY RAND()");

    foreach ( $result as $k => $v )   {

  $c_name         = stripslashes($v->company_name);
$c_opis         = stripslashes($v->company_desc);
$c_mob_nr       = stripslashes($v->tel);
$c_nip      = stripslashes($v->company_nip);          
?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_name; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_name; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_nip ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_nip ?></td>
        </tr>
         <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_mob_nr ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_mob_nr ?></td>
        </tr>
         <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_opis ?></td>
            <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $c_opis ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can do something like this in query
"WHERE (company_id%2) = 0", It gives you even only and same you do for other page but just change WHERE condition 
"WHERE (company_id%2) = 1"

Comment: @FaranAli And ID's are as follows `1`, `3`, `9`, `115` than you will have only right side, right?

Comment: yes, it's work like this@Justinas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do also this way

```
<table>
    <tbody>

<?php 
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT company_province, company_district, company_city, company_name, tel, company_nip, company_desc FROM test WHERE company_province = '$woj' AND company_district = '$pow' AND company_city = '$nazwa' ORDER BY RAND()");

for ($i=0; $i <count($result); $i++) {

    $c_name         = stripslashes($result[$i]->company_name);
    $c_opis         = stripslashes($result[$i]->company_desc);
    $c_mob_nr       = stripslashes($result[$i]->tel);
    $c_nip          = stripslashes($result[$i]->company_nip);   
    $i++
    if ( ($i) <  count($result))      {
        $c_name2         = stripslashes($result[$i]->company_name);
        $c_opis2         = stripslashes($result[$i]->company_desc);
        $c_mob_nr2       = stripslashes($result[$i]->tel);
        $c_nip2      = stripslashes($result[$i]->company_nip);   
    }  else {
        $c_name2         = '';
        $c_opis2         = '';
        $c_mob_nr2       = '';
        $c_nip2      = ''; 
    }


    echo '<tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;">' . $c_name .'</td>
            <td style="width: 50%;">' . $c_name2 .'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;">' . $c_nip .'</td>
            <td style="width: 50%;">' . $c_nip2  .'</td>
        </tr>
         <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;">' . $c_mob_nr .'</td>
            <td style="width: 50%;">' . $c_mob_nr2 .'</td>
        </tr>
         <tr style="height: 50%;">
            <td style="width: 50%;">' . $c_opis.'</td>
            <td style="width: 50%;">' . $c_opis2 .'</td>
        </tr> ':
    }

    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I got " unexpected T_IF"    in this line " if ( ($i) <  count($result)) {"

Comment: I have update the answer  (some part of code was hidden ).. try again

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I was happy to soon. Your code works, but only then, when there is alteast 2 records. If there is only one, it does not show :(

Comment: I have update the answer should work with only one or odd records

Comment: yep, it's working ^^ Thanks. I have one more question, Can u do that it will not show an empty table on the right, when there is only one record on the left? Of course, as it is now it can be, it's just an optionally. And thank you very much for your great help :)

Comment: You can do it testing before the loop how many rows you obtain and the if you get only one rows don't perform the loop code but direct echoing a single  rows  with width 100% .. properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your data first, only than display:

```
$rows = [];
$i = 1; // use $k + 1 if it's indexed array

foreach ( $result as $k => $v )   {
    $key = $i % 2 == 0 ? 'right' : 'left';
    $rows[] = [
        $key => [
            'name' => stripslashes($v->company_name),
            'opis' => stripslashes($v->company_desc),
            'mob_nr' => stripslashes($v->tel),
            'nip' => stripslashes($v->company_nip),
        ];
    ];

    $i++;
}

echo '<table>';

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['left']['name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['right']['name']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['left']['nip']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['right']['nip']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['left']['mob_nr']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['right']['mob_nr']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['left']['opis']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['right']['opis']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

For each gets one record at a time, and then you actually coded it to echo the same variable twice. You should let the for each complete and build an array that you can loop through with an index incrementing by 2 each loop.

```
<?php
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT company_province, company_district, company_city, company_name, tel, company_nip, company_desc FROM test WHERE company_province = '$woj' AND company_district = '$pow' AND company_city = '$nazwa' ORDER BY RAND()");
$customers = array();
x = 0; 
foreach ( $result as $k => $v )   {
    $customers[x].c_name = stripslashes($v->company_name);
    $customers[x].c_opis = stripslashes($v->company_desc);
    $customers[x].c_mob_nr = stripslashes($v->tel);
    $customers[x].c_nip = stripslashes($v->company_nip); 
    x++;
}

for(i=0;i<sizeof($customer);i=i+2){ 
// lets drop to back html for sanity 
?>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr style="height: 50%;">
        <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $customer[i].c_name; ?></td>
        <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $customer[i+1].c_name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 50%;">
        <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $customer[i].c_nip ?></td>
        <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $customer[i+1].c_nip ?></td>
    </tr>
     <tr style="height: 50%;">
        <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $customer[i].c_mob_nr ?></td>
        <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $customer[i+1].c_mob_nr?></td>
    </tr>
     <tr style="height: 50%;">
        <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $customer[i].c_opis ?></td>
        <td style="width: 50%;"><?php echo $customer[i+1].c_opis ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php 
} //end for loop
?>
```

Comment: I do not know why but I get a syntax error, unexpected '[' for $customers = [];

Comment: I'm sorry it's new array. I have edited it. So many languages going on in my head.         $customers = array();

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but i got an error in loop:    for($i=0; $ii=$customers.length(); $i<$ii; $i=$i+2;) - unexpected ';', expecting ')' .

Comment: PHP doesn't like my javascript for loop shortcut double initialization, I fixed it. And php prefers count() to length, fixed that as well.

Comment: "count() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given"  I tried also $i<count($customer); But its shows no results.